# Moving a date between tables is causing error ORA-01841

Tags: oracle

Here's my script:

```
INSERT INTO BRAND_RECORD
SELECT 
    STRENGTH,
    GENERIC_NAME,
    TO_DATE(a1.FIRST_CLAIM_DATE) as INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE 
FROM DRUG_INFO
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        FIRST_CLAIM_DATE, 
        SEQUENTIAL_ID 
    FROM DRUG_INFO 
    WHERE 
        SEQUENTIAL_ID IN 
        (
            SELECT MIN(SEQUENTIAL_ID)
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT * 
                FROM DRUG_INFO
                WHERE 
                    SEQUENTIAL_ID NOT IN 
                    (
                        SELECT MIN(SEQUENTIAL_ID) 
                        FROM DRUG_INFO
                        GROUP BY GENERIC_NAME, STRENGTH
                    )
            )
            GROUP BY GENERIC_NAME, STRENGTH
        )
) a1
    ON (a1.SEQUENTIAL_ID = DRUG_INFO.SEQUENTIAL_ID + 1);
```

Summary: Everything after `INSERT INTO BRAND_RECORD` works perfectly well. It is a query that produces a `STRENGTH, GENERIC_NAME`, and `INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE`.
`BRAND_RECORD` is a table with the columns `STRENGTH, GENERIC_NAME, INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE`.

However, I get the following error:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713
>   and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
>   *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>   *Action:   Input year in the specified range

This seems like some sort of conversion problem. But I'm selecting a date and putting it into a table that takes a date! Any idea what the problem might be?

UPDATE: I changed my default date format to MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS. I now get the following error when I try this:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found
>   where a numeric was expected 01858. 00000 - "a non-numeric character
>   was found where a numeric was expected" *Cause: The input data to be
>   converted using a date format model was incorrect. The input data did
>   not contain a number where a number was required by the format model.
>   *Action: Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the elements match in number and type. Then retry the operation. Error
>   starting at line : 1 in command - INSERT INTO BRAND_RECORD Error at
>   Command Line : 1 Column : 24 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00926:
>   missing VALUES keyword 00926. 00000 - "missing VALUES keyword" *Cause:
>   *Action:

Here are my create table statements for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE BRAND_RECORD 
(
  GENERIC_NAME VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE DATE 
, STRENGTH VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE DATAL03 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL;    

CREATE TABLE DRUG_INFO 
(
  DIN VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, TRADE_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, FORM VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) 
, STRENGTH VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) 
, GENERIC_NAME VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, MANUFACTURER VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CR_DATE DATE 
, NOC_DATE DATE 
, FIRST_CLAIM_DATE DATE 
, SEQUENTIAL_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE DATAL03 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL;
```

Comment: If you are selecting a date then why do you have TO_DATE(a1.FIRST_CLAIM_DATE) ? Seems to me that a1.FIRST_CLAIM_DATE is actually of a character type, and you're trying to do a conversion to a date. Since you didn't specify a date format, the default is used, and you got into trouble because your "dates" are not formatted that way. Specify the date format in to_date() function explicitly.

Comment: That TO_DATE was an attempt to fix the problem. FIRST_CLAIM_DATE is without a doubt a date type.

Maybe the problem is that one table holds dates in a different format? How do I change that on a per-table basis? How would I even see?

Comment: Did you try to manually inspect the data you get from the select? Can you post DRUG_INFO create table statement?

Comment: I have manually inspected them. I posted both of the create table statements above.

Comment: Strange. Could you explicitly state columns in BRAND_RECORD in the insert part (write: insert into BRAND_RECORD(STRENGTH, GENERIC_NAME, INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE) SELECT... )

Comment: That worked! Weird! Do you have any idea why that worked?

Comment: Well, not that weird actually, the database thought you were trying to insert GENERIC_NAME (the second column in your select query) into INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE (the second column in the targeted table). That's why its always best to be explicit.

Comment: @zgguy - maybe you could write this up as an answer and maybe Daniel, you could accept it. That way, anyone with a similar problem in future will be able to find a solution.

Comment: If zgg doesn't post it sometime soon I'll post it myself, just don't wanna steal credit.

Comment: I f you mark something that you haven't written yourself, it's OK to give credit. I believe that the terms of posting on Stackexchange mean that one's contributions are under the Creative Commons with attribution, so it's impossible to "steal credit". But, it would be good to give @zgguy the chance to post his own material as an answer and get the reputation points when you accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I can live without the reputation score. OP already wrote the answer to the question, what's important is that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zgguy answered this in comments:

Explicitly stating columns in the insert solved the problem, as it was trying to put columns in the wrong columns.

```
INSERT INTO BRAND_RECORD (STRENGTH, GENERIC_NAME, INTERCHANGEABILITY_DATE)
```

Comment: How did you expect Oracle to know what columns were the 'right' columns if you didn't make it explicit? You should always, always, include the column names in an insert.

Comment: Yeah I was being a little dumb. I figured SQL would automatically match columns with the same names.

Comment: Ah, I see. That would be a reasonable enough thing to do (except typos would result in exceedingly hard to find bugs) but no RDBMS I know of does that. Much better would be for an error to be returned unless columns are specified - that'd prevent all sorts of issues like this.